# How I get SUM in core data

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5

I have core data with entity (Deductions) it has three attributes first one (deductionName) second is (deductionStatus) and the last one is (deductionAmount).

Now I would like to get the SUM of (deductionAmount) if the (deductionStatus) == 1

(deductionStatus) is a boolean.

```
return [[[self.fetchedDeductionData fetchedObjects] valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.deductionAmount"]floatValue];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious solution is fetching only the `deductionAmount` and doing the sum yourself (Since I don't really think there's a difference between SQLite doing the some and you doing the sum):

```
// build your NSFetchRequest

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"deductionStatus == 1"];
[request setPredicate:predicate]; 
[request setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
[request setPropertiesToFetch: [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"deductionAmount", nil]];

// execute fetch request

// iterate through the array
CGFloat sum = 0;
for (NSDictionary *dictionary in fetchedResults) {
    NSNumber *amount = [dictionary objectForKey:@"deductionAmount"];
    sum = sum + [amount doubleValue]
}
```

Comment: `NSInteger x = [[self.fetchedDeductionData fetchedObjects] count];
    
    float sum = 0;
    
    for (int y = 0; y < x; y++) {
        if ([[[[[self.fetchedDeductionData fetchedObjects]objectAtIndex:y]valueForKey:@"deductionStatus"]description] isEqualToString:@"1"]) {
            sum = sum + [[[[self.fetchedDeductionData fetchedObjects]objectAtIndex:y]valueForKey:@"deductionAmount"]floatValue];
        }
    }
    
    return sum;`

Comment: Don't use count and old for-loop to iterate through the array if you don't need index, for-in loop is faster.